# JQueryMobile collapsible header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
var dw=function(string){
document.write(string+"-Hello");
}
<h1><script>dw("Hi")</script></h1>   //Hi-Hello
```

This works fine. But when i put this header inside a collapsible, it just prints Hi-Hello and does not show collapsible.

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3><script>dw("Hi")</script></h3>
 <p>collapsible content.</p>
</div>
```

Is there any workaround to change collapsible header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to change the Header-Text of a Collapsible, give the Collapsible an ID or a class:

```
<div id="myCollapsible" data-role="collapsible">
<h3>OldTitle</h3>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Since JQM uses jQuery, you could use some jQuery-Magic, e.g.:

```
<script>
$("#myCollapsible .ui-btn-text").text("My New Title");
</script>
```

If you want to change it on "pageshow" or "pagecreate" you can try this:

```
<script>
// $("#myPageId").bind ... would be possible too
$(document).bind("pageshow", function(){     
    $("#myCollapsible .ui-btn-text").text("My New Title");
});
</script>
```

Hope I could help you out :)